# How to save values permanently in Local storage using selenium in Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, local-storage

I am trying to save values in Local storage so that I'm able to access them again after I close and reopen a new session with selenium. I'm able to save and access values from the same session but when I close the browser then try to access the stored variable, it shows as null:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.execute_script("localStorage.setItem('testkey', 'myValue');")
driver.execute_script("alert (localStorage.getItem('testkey'));")
```

The alert occurs as expected when I run the above but when I close and reopen the browser and run the above code after commenting out the `setItem` line, the alert shows null. How can I get this working, or is there any other way I can persist values that are set from javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You are using some javascript code to store the value **with driver instance**. So once you close/quit the browser. session get terminated that's why same code won't work in this case with new driver instance.

Use environment in Python to store and access the variable throughout the execution

```
driver.execute_script("localStorage.setItem('testkey', 'myValue');")
driver.execute_script("alert (localStorage.getItem('testkey'));")

value = driver.switch_to.alert.text

# Set environment variables
os.environ['keyword'] = value

# get the environment variable
print(os.getenv('keyword'))
```

import below module:

```
import os
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have is getting the value from javascript to python. I can only get the value when a button is clicked, for example if I fill in a username and press submit, I need to be able to save this value somehow and access it on a new session

Comment: @West, Update the answer please check

Comment: You can use this line `os.getenv('keyword')` to get your value in other test

Comment: Oh sorry the use of alert was just so I can easily test the code but I wont be using an alert in my final code

Comment: `os.environ` isnt persisting the data either. The variable is only available on current session. When I rerun the script the value is gone.

Comment: Yes, That's how it designed for. as I've mentioned _throughout the execution_  You should go with some temp file storage to pick the value from last execution.

Answer (score 0):

Oh actually this is dead simple I finally figured it out.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.execute_script("localStorage.setItem('testkey', 'myValue');")
myvariable = driver.execute_script("return localStorage.getItem('testkey');")
```

Then from python you can store the value anywhere you want for easy retrieval next time.

```
dicti = {'storage':myvariable}
json.dump(dicti, open("stored.json","w"))
```

Comment: Even this code is not able to retrieve the value while re execute the script. This is repeating same thing each time. first set the value and then retrieve the same value

Comment: @NarendraR No this code does retrieve the value from the browser side I 've edited my answer assigning the returned value to make this clear. Not sure what the downvote is for stackoverflow is getting too unprofessional.The snippet I posted in my question was just a short simplified sample of my overall code but the full actual code first injects javascript to listen to a click of the submit button. A user then fills a form and presses the submit button. Form values are then passed to python and saved locally for use in other ways. How is this repeating the same thing?